# Check if a varchar column only has alphabetical chars

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a check constraint that only allows inserts of alphabetic chars like: 'A' 'Marie', not allowing something like '1' '*#€*a'.

At the moment o have this expression:

```
CONSTRAINT CK_Pn CHECK (Name LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]%'
```

Comment: But names *can* have characters other than A-z. What about someone called "O'Conner" or "Smith-Brown"? Can those people just not use your application?

Comment: Did you overlook accented characters?

Comment: Or stuff like German umlauts (`ä ö ü`), French accents (`é è à`) and so forth?? Lots of European languages have special characters of some sort ..... you'd be locking all those names out, too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not like`:

```
CONSTRAINT CK_Pn CHECK (Name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]%'))
```

That is, `Name` has no characters that are not alphabetic characters.